# When signing my flutter app i cannot build the app *edited*

Tags: android, gradle, flutter, signing

So i want to publish my flutter app to the play store. I signed the app but after that the app won't build. When i try to build my app through the appbundle it returns this:

```
C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\AndroidStudioProjects\tab_truth_true\tab>flutter build appbundle
Initializing gradle...                                              1,1s
Resolving dependencies...                                           5,6s
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...
Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                        11,9s
Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

When i try to build the app through fat APK i get a longer error but still a mystery:¨

```
C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\AndroidStudioProjects\tab_truth_true\tab>flutter build apk
You are building a fat APK that includes binaries for android-arm, android-arm64.
If you are deploying the app to the Play Store, it's recommended to use app bundles or split the APK to reduce the APK size.
    To generate an app bundle, run:
        flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64
        Learn more on: https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle
    To split the APKs per ABI, run:
        flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64 --split-per-abi
        Learn more on:  https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-abi-split
Initializing gradle...                                              1,4s
Resolving dependencies...                                          23,0s
Note: C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\Desktop\Appen\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\firebase_admob-0.9.0+9\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\firebaseadmob\AdRequestBuil
derFactory.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\tbsvst18tedbom\Desktop\Appen\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.2.5\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.jav
a uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...

Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... Done                     133,5s (!)
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

I'll add the app-level build.gradle file if that helps.

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new FileNotFoundException()("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file('C:\\Users\\tbsvst18tedbom\\Desktop\\Appen\\KeyStore\\TABKEY.jks')
            storePassword '***'
            keyAlias = 'TABTRUTH1'
            keyPassword '***'
        }
    }
    compileSdkVersion 29

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tab.tab"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            multiDexEnabled true
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard.pro'
        }
    }
}

    flutter {
        source '../..'
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.3.60"
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-rc-1'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:19.0.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0'
    }

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

I hope that anyone can help me with this weird error message. I have no idea what so ever of what the problem may be since the app built fine just before I signed it.

If you need any files just say the word and I'll edit the question.

Thank you so much!

EDIT1
As requested, this is the pubspec.yaml file

```
name: tab
description: TAB2

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  url_launcher: ^5.0.0
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.0+9
  firebase_core: ^0.4.2
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.6


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter_launcher_icons: "^0.7.3"

flutter_icons:
  android: true
  ios: true
  image_path: "Images/Logo_utan_text.png"

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
    - Images/logotype.png
    - Images/Logo_utan_text.png

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:
  # fonts:
  #   - family: Schyler
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Regular.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/Schyler-Italic.ttf
  #         style: italic
  #   - family: Trajan Pro
  #     fonts:
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro.ttf
  #       - asset: fonts/TrajanPro_Bold.ttf
  #         weight: 700
  #
  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

After further investigation, I found the build it created. The folder is there with all info but there is no APK. I belive that the apk fails to be signed so therefore it does not get created? Correct me if im wrong.

Thank you!

EDIT3
When I run gradle sync i get this gradle issue

```
INFO: API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
It will be removed at the end of 2019.
For more information, see https://d.android.com/r/tools/task-configuration-avoidance.
To determine what is calling variantOutput.getProcessResources(), use -Pandroid.debug.obsoleteApi=true on the command line to display more information.
Affected Modules: app
```

Does anyone know what to do to fix this?

Comment: add your pubspec.yaml

Comment: I don’t use windows so I’m not sure, but why you  use two backslashes to indicate the path? I think the problem is with the signing section so this one might be the reason.

Comment: @Ggriffo I have updated my question with the pubspec.yaml file. I also changed the path indication to forwardslashes but with no luck at solving the issue.

Comment: after going through your pub file some dep require some configs eg https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob

Comment: I looked through the link and my pubspec but i'm not sure what i need to do. As far as I can see, nothing is wrong?

Comment: @Ggriffo the thing is, the build works when i don't sign the app. As soon as i try to sign it, it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as if I had named the keyAlias wrong, it works now that I have changed it. Thank you so much for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Flutter made a guide on [how to sign an app](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android#signing-the-app) which worked for me. You should give it a try.

Comment: I have tried this method but it also returns this error.